# Declaring actions through RegisterReceiver or in AndroidManifest

Tags: android

I want to start service if screen is on.I think I have to use `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`. But I'm not sure where should I declare it in `AndroidManifest` or through `RegisterReceiver` method? As I understood if I will declare this action in the `AndroidManifest` my service will be started even if user hasn't reached specific point in my app cause action was committed. So if want to start service after user has reached that specific point and also screen is on I should use `RegisterReceiver` method, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm not sure where should I declare it in AndroidManifest or through RegisterReceiver method?

`ACTION_SCREEN_ON` only works via `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Well, and what about ACTION_USER_PRESENT?Is it work only via RegisterReceiver? And I assume that ACTION_SCREEN_OFF also works only via RegisterReceiver,right?

Comment: @S.Drumble4: "what about ACTION_USER_PRESENT?Is it work only via RegisterReceiver?" -- I think so, but I am less certain of that one. "And I assume that ACTION_SCREEN_OFF also works only via RegisterReceiver,right?" -- correct.